# SQLAlchemy Many to One Join

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a many to one relationship between two `SQL` tables using `SQLAlchemy`. For example:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    child = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
```

What I would like to be able to do is be able to add information from the `Child` class to the parent. I tried a `join` query:

```
result = session.query(Parent).join(Child).all()
```

While this query adds the appropriate `Child` object to the `Parent` object at `parent.child` it only returns the first parent for each child, i.e. I have four parents and two children in my database and this query only returns parents 1 and 3. How do I fix the query to return all four parents? The second I have is if I wanted to just add the child's name to the parent, not the entire child object, as `parent.child_name` how would I go about doing that?

Comment: To get all of the entries for the many category of a many to one relationship, you need to use `outerjoin`: `session.query(Parent).outerjoin(Child).all()` Still not sure about the second question.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to get all parents when joining to children

The issue is that some parents do not have children, so using a normal join will exclude them.  Use an outer join instead.  Also, just adding a join won't actually load the children.  You should specify `contains_eager` or `joinedload` to load the child with the parent.

```
# use contains_eager when you are joining and filtering on the relationship already
session.query(Parent).join(Parent.child).filter(Child.name == 'Max').options(contains_eager(Parent.child))

# use joinedload when you do not need to join and filter, but still want to load the relationship
session.query(Parent).options(joinedload(Parent.child))
```

#### How to add child_name to the parent

You want to use an [association proxy](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html).

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class Parent(Base):
    child = relationship('Child')
    child_name = association_proxy('child', 'name')

# you can filter queries with proxies:
session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.child_name == 'Min')
```

There are some cool things you can do with association proxies, be sure to read the docs for more information.